# Geo Nodes: looking for example of Geo Node *path* in a driver function

Tags: geometry-nodes, drivers

I am trying to pass a Geonode data_path that can be used in a driver nodes variable, for example a Group Output attribute, or even a Stored Named Attribute, from one GeoNode to another.

[image]

I have object ["mesh with stored attr and output attr"] that is passing through the "Matl Idx2" group input value to both an group output and a Stored Attribute .

Alas I managed to find one data_path that was accepted without an error, but isn't working:
[image]

And these (copy data path) pasted into the field gives errors:
[image]

I should have 2 red objects and the sphere should be at Z=1.1 if all is working, but alas:
[image]

In my [image] you'll see that I know how to use a reference a GN named attribute as in the red object ["mesh using stored attr"].

Comment: In your 3rd screenshot (the Edit Driver popup), for *Prop* you must not specify 'NodeTree' but 'Object' and then choose the object with the second dropdown menu because the object has the modifier. Then you can enter the copied datapath. But this will give you not a number but the *Attribute Name* that you've entered for the GN group output of the GN modifier of the object 'mesh with stored attr and output attr'. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/KStF2.jpg). The attribute name is a String and the driver's target wants a number. So 'hello' becomes 0.000 in the driver.

Answer (score 2):

It's looks like that you are trying to do something not possible. This reference

```
nodes['Store Named Attribute'].inputs[6]
```

is not a number, it is the socket itself. (and yes, index is 6, not 1). But anyway, socket is an abstract representation of this node element, but it is not the data which it holds.
The only data that you can get from socket it is a default value, but not the computed value from nodetree:

```
 nodes['Store Named Attribute'].inputs[6].default_value
```

This is `1` in your node tree. But I suppose this is not that you are looking for. But computed value is not assessable, because it may lead to textures, field values, or context values, that are depends on geometry data, so cannot be reproduced by a single value.

I suppose you can grab data for driver from socket input of modifier.